# How can you get the Disk Number of an offline clustered physical disk resource in Windows 2008 R2 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

Using PowerShell, how can you get the Disk Number of an offline clustered physical disk resource on a 2008 R2 Failover Cluster.
I can open Failover Cluster Manager, look at the properties of the offline disk and the disk number is listed there, that is what I am after.
Basically I want to be able to query the clustered resources and then get the disk numbers for them.

Thank you,

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you try `Get-ClusterSharedVolume`? is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That command does not return anything. The failover cluster is not using Cluster Shared Volumes, it it using standard volumes in which only the owner node has access to the volume.